# How to Read XML and Generate SQL Insert for Call Data Records

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, xml

I am trying to write a VB Script to read a XML file (downloaded daily) and insert the information into a MSSQL DB.  The content of the XML is a list of CDRs (Call Data Records).  I need to parse the file and insert the cdr's into a table.  I'm a Ruby,Perl,PHP,Javascript,SQL,... programer.

But I've really never written any VB Script.  I've done some googling and find a number of examples on how to generate XML from a SQL Query, but not the reverse.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A sample of the XML would be useful. Or at least a link to CDRs for those that are not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @James Mohler's comment. It would be better if you could provide us with an example with the sensitive data ommited as CDRs contain personal information.

I would recommend searching [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for help with your question as within seconds I found an answer that will help solve the first part of reading in the XML.

```
Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 
objXMLDoc.load("example.xml")

Set Root = objXMLDoc.documentElement 


For Each Elem In NodeList 
   SET ElementValue = Elem.getElementsByTagName("ElementName")(0)
Next
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254600/reading-xml-file-with-vbscript)